# providing logs to the users

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

Scenario...  Load balanced webfarm with several Apache/Tomcat machines crunching the requests.

Developers need access to the catalina.out file.  Naturally this is different on all machines.

What method/logic/tactic would you use/suggest in such a situation?  Unfortunately reconfiguring tomcat to shoot catalina.out on an NFS export is not an option.

Do you know of any cute web front ends to logfile directories?  :)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/96720/open-source-tomcat-log-viewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used Graylog for this before:

http://graylog2.org/

It provides a nice web interface that is intuitive and it was really simple to setup.  We have since outgrown the built-in functionality of Graylog and are using Splunk (mentioned in the answer @quanta linked).  It provides a much nicer front-end and lets you build reports and alerts so you can get notified about certain conditions based on very extensive criteria.

Comment: HOT , How scalable is graylog?

Comment: It doesn't really support distributed backends so its fairly limited, but you can do hundreds of millions of events in a single system pretty easily.

Comment: What if you have a centralized rsyslog server... can you push all your logs form rsyslog -> graylog? :)  That way not modifying all systems, but adding on graylog?

Comment: Yeah, that way works really nicely and it makes it easier to change solutions if you need to later (and lets old school dudes use grep if they really want to).

Comment: THANK YOU !  I will implement today and see what happens :)  Will stress test and revert :)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using logstash to slurp the data in from the log file, then you can push it to Graylog2 (and provide a 'stream' to allow users to read the logs). Splunk is nice but pricey.